# why is php acting different when run through the shell or a local webserver?

Tags: php

I have a small project that i have been working on it basically downloads the contents of given links (Caldav Calender links) and merges the ics files. the problem now is when i use the command
`file_put_contents` or `file_get_contents()` i get mixed results. when run through a local webserver it downloads the correct contents but when run through the terminal it semes to be downloading the website contents rather than the supposed download contents.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>public-calendars - sabre/dav </title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/remote.php/dav/?sabreAction=asset&amp;assetName=favicon.ico"   type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"    href="/remote.php/dav/?sabreAction=asset&amp;assetName=sabredav.css"     type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"    href="/remote.php/dav/?sabreAction=asset&amp;assetName=openiconic%2Fopen-iconic.css" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="/remote.php/dav/"><img src="/remote.php/dav/?sabreAction=asset&amp;assetName=sabredav.png" alt="sabre/dav" /> public-calendars/ysT7xJQmSxx2RTKZ</a>
        </div>
    </header>

    <nav><a href="/remote.php/dav/public-calendars" class="btn">⇤ Go to parent</a> <a href="?sabreAction=plugins" class="btn"><span class="oi" data-glyph="puzzle-piece"></span> Plugins</a></nav><section><h1>Nodes</h1>
<table class="nodeTable"><tr><td class="nameColumn"><a href="/remote.php/dav/public-calendars/ysT7xJQmSxx2RTKZ/0A4D04A5-90FF-477B-A8DC-C703E1FACA1F.ics"><span class="oi" data-glyph="file"></span> 0A4D04A5-90FF-477B-A8DC-C703E1FACA1F.ics</a></td><td class="typeColumn">File</td><td>447 bytes</td><td>May 1, 2022, 5:15 pm</td><td></td><td><a href="/remote.php/dav/public-calendars/ysT7xJQmSxx2RTKZ/0A4D04A5-90FF-477B-A8DC-C703E1FACA1F.ics?sabreAction=info"><span class="oi" data-glyph="info"></span></a></td></tr><tr><td class="nameColumn"><a 

/// i croped a lot out because it just keept on beeing the same
```

there is not much that i could try because i couldnt quite find out what the strict problem here is. it just keeps missbehaving wiredly maybe someone of you has experienced similar behavior and is able to help me out.

here is the code used:

```
<?php

function processFile($i, $size, $file)
{
    file_put_contents('test.ics', file_get_contents($file, FALSE, NULL));
    $lines = file($file);
    $beginEvent = array_search("BEGIN:VEVENT", $lines);
    $reverselines = array_reverse($lines, true);
    $endEvent = array_search('END:VEVENT', $reverselines);

    if ($size == 1) {
        // do nothing
    } elseif ($i == 0) {
        //First calendar file entry: Takes in also first part of meta data
        $lines = array_slice($lines, 0, $endEvent + 1);
    } elseif ($i == $size - 1) {
        //Last calendar file entry: Take last part of meta data
        $lines = array_slice($lines, $beginEvent);
    } else {
        // Slice only Event information, beginnen and ending with "VEVENT" headers
        $lines = array_slice($lines, $beginEvent, $endEvent - $beginEvent + 1);
    }
    return $lines;
}

$links = file("links.txt");
$size = count($links) - 1;
$result = array();
$tempresult = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    $tempresult = processFile($i, $size, $links[$i]);
    //print_r($tempresult);
    $result = array_merge($result, $tempresult);
}

$file = fopen("output.ics", "w");
foreach ($result as $value) {
    fwrite($file, $value . "\n");
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Looks your terminal is unable to create an http request. which is correct . use curl / python for such kind of things.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).